# Elasticsearch for uncertain amount i18n

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) in a [laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) project.

I have a `products` table like below

```sql
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` JSON NOT NULL,
);
```

The title of each product will have multiple languages, and the type of language is uncertain

```
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     id     |                                   title                                   |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1     |{"en-US":"Toyota Cruiser","ja-JP":"トヨタクルーザー","zh-CN":"丰田酷路泽"}    |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      2     |{"en-US":"Subaru Outback","ja-JP":"スバルアウトバック"}                      |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      3     |{"zh-CN":"路虎 揽胜","ja-JP":"ランドローバーレンジローバー"}                   |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      4     |{"en-US":"BMW X5"}                                                         |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I create a elasticsearch index for `products` table which supports search in i18n?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have the language identifier in your database as `en-us`, `zh-cn` which means before storing the title, you know the language of product, than you can simply use the [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and can add a new language sub-field for all the available languages in Elasticsearch.

You can have a look at [all the current supported languages in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#analysis-lang-analyzer) and add all the sub-fields in beginning or change the mapping and add a new language sub-field as you get it in your system.

Comment: @Ntx, glad it was useful +1 for your question :)